# SqliteException While Dropping Tables (main.table)

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been using SQLite for a while in my application. I haven't had any issues, but this was my first upgrade. I incremented my DB version, and implemented onUpgrade as such:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOCKED);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Created table LOCKED_BUNCH_MEMBER");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_HIDDEN);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Created table HIDDEN_BUNCH_MEMBER");
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine! But on logout I drop all tables, and that's when I get a crazy weird error:

```
12-29 00:55:10.365: E/AndroidRuntime(1020): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: main.bunch (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS buddy
```

What the heck is this? I don't have a schema called main, and I've never seen this. This is the LAST drop table statement, and it fails. Anybody have an idea as to why?

Did I do the upgrade wrong?

```
public static LBDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new LBDatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private LBDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDY);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUNCH);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BCAST_BUNCH);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUNCH_MEMBER);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BCAST_BUNCH_MEMBER);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOCKED_BUNCH_MEMBER);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_HIDDEN_BUNCH_MEMBER);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_THREAD);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_THREAD_MEMBER);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_THREAD_MESSAGE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BUDDY_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOCKED_BUNCH_MEMBER);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Created table LOCKED_BUNCH_MEMBER");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_HIDDEN_BUNCH_MEMBER);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Created table HIDDEN_BUNCH_MEMBER");
    }
}

public void dropAllTables() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + THREAD_MESSAGE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + THREAD_MEMBER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + THREAD_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LOCKED_BUNCH_MEMBER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + HIDDEN_BUNCH_MEMBER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BCAST_BUNCH_MEMBER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BUNCH_MEMBER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BCAST_BUNCH_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BUNCH_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BUDDY_REQUEST_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BUDDY_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "recreated tables");
}
```

**EDIT**: added the tables that got created when updated:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_LOCKED_BUNCH_MEMBER  =
            "CREATE TABLE " + LOCKED_BUNCH_MEMBER_TABLE + "(" + BUNCH_MEMBER_BUNCH_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + BUNCH_MEMBER_USERNAME + " VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, "
                    + BUNCH_MEMBER_FIRST_NAME + " VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, "
                    + BUNCH_MEMBER_LAST_NAME + " VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, "
                    + BUNCH_MEMBER_VISIBILITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, "
                    + "PRIMARY KEY (" + BUNCH_MEMBER_BUNCH_ID + ", " + BUNCH_MEMBER_USERNAME + "), "
                    + "FOREIGN KEY (" + BUNCH_MEMBER_BUNCH_ID + ") " +
                    " REFERENCES " + BUNCH_TABLE + "(" + BUNCH_ID + ")" +
                    " ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE, "
                    + "FOREIGN KEY (" + BUNCH_MEMBER_USERNAME + ") " +
                    " REFERENCES " + BUDDY_TABLE + "(" + BUDDY_USERNAME + ")" +
                    " ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_HIDDEN_BUNCH_MEMBER  =
            "CREATE TABLE " + HIDDEN_BUNCH_MEMBER_TABLE + "(" + BUNCH_MEMBER_BUNCH_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + BUNCH_MEMBER_USERNAME + " VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, "
                    + BUNCH_MEMBER_FIRST_NAME + " VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, "
                    + BUNCH_MEMBER_LAST_NAME + " VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, "
                    + BUNCH_MEMBER_VISIBILITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, "
                    + "PRIMARY KEY (" + BUNCH_MEMBER_BUNCH_ID + ", " + BUNCH_MEMBER_USERNAME + "), "
                    + "FOREIGN KEY (" + BUNCH_MEMBER_BUNCH_ID + ") " +
                    " REFERENCES " + BUNCH_TABLE + "(" + BUNCH_ID + ")" +
                    " ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE, "
                    + "FOREIGN KEY (" + BUNCH_MEMBER_USERNAME + ") " +
                    " REFERENCES " + BUDDY_TABLE + "(" + BUDDY_USERNAME + ")" +
                    " ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)";
```

Comment: `SQLiteException: no such table:`

Comment: Post your total code

Comment: show  statement sqlite please!

Comment: what is `CREATE_TABLE_LOCKED` I guess add here your table name

Comment: Post your total `sqlite` code .Need to check create table statement

Comment: statement sql : CREATE TABLE table_name(
   column1 datatype,
   column2 datatype,
   column3 datatype,
   .....
   columnN datatype,
   PRIMARY KEY( one or more columns )
);

Comment: Post your CREATE_TABLE_LOCKED (content) please!
Eg: String CREATE_TABLE_LOCKED ="Create tabe....."

Comment: The thing about this error is that all tables get created fine. "main.bunch" is not a table I've created, it's one that SQLite creates I believe. We need to figure out what's causing the issue on delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over

        //Drop the main table or the database table 
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(//Drop the table statement));
        //reCreate database table 
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
```

in your Case you dont need to recreate the database table so you but a Condition in the onCreate() Statemen

Comment: Can't do this. Need to preserve user data.

Comment: im sorry but i submit my answer before i finish it :(

Comment: Ok just Make a Condition on th onCreate() and Do the Other Cleaning Operation on the other tables but first you have to save the references to those tables so you can drop them

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

CreateDatabase.class:

```
public class CreateDatabase {
public static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDb;

private SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Supporter.sqlite";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public CreateDatabase(Context ctx) {
    this.dbHelper = new DBAdapterHelper(ctx);
}

public static CreateDatabase create(Context ctx) {
    return new CreateDatabase(ctx);

}

public synchronized SQLiteDatabase open() {
    if (sqliteDb == null || !sqliteDb.isOpen()) {
        try {
            sqliteDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sqliteDb;
}

public void close() {
    if (sqliteDb != null && sqliteDb.isOpen()) {
        sqliteDb.close();
    }

}

private static class DBAdapterHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBAdapterHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            ItemUserSchema.onCreate(db);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

}}
```

ItemUserSchema.class

```
public class ItemUserSchema {


public static final String TABLE_ITEM_USER = "tbItemUser";

public static final String KEY_icon_color = "icon_color";

public static final String KEY_status_text = "status_text";

public static final String KEY_icon = "icon";
public static final String KEY_time = "time";
public static final String KEY_link_share = "link_share";
public static final String KEY_address = "address";
public static final String KEY_item_id = "item_id";
public static final String KEY_company = "company";
public static final String KEY_name = "name";
public static final String KEY_job_salary = "job_salary";
public static final String KEY_job_mobile = "job_mobile";
public static final String KEY_job_email = "job_email";
public static final String KEY_cate_name = "cate_name";


private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_APPARAM = "Create Table "
        + TABLE_ITEM_USER + "(" + KEY_icon_color + " text,"
        + KEY_status_text + " text,"
        + KEY_icon + " text,"
        + KEY_time + " text,"
        + KEY_link_share + " text,"
        + KEY_address + " text,"
        + KEY_item_id + " INTEGER,"
        + KEY_company + " text,"
        + KEY_name + " text,"
        + KEY_job_salary + " text,"
        + KEY_job_mobile + " text,"
        + KEY_job_email + " text,"
        + KEY_cate_name + " text)";

public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_APPARAM);
    Log.e("TABLE_ITEM_USER", DATABASE_CREATE_APPARAM);
}}
```

ItemUserDao.class

```
public class ItemUserDao {

private final SQLiteDatabase db;

public ItemUserDao(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super();
    this.db = db;
}

public long insertItemUser(ItemUserEntity itemUserEntity) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_icon_color, itemUserEntity.getIcon_color());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_status_text, itemUserEntity.getStatus_text());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_icon, itemUserEntity.getIcon());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_time, itemUserEntity.getTime());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_link_share, itemUserEntity.getLink_share());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_address, itemUserEntity.getAddress());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_item_id, itemUserEntity.getItem_id());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_company, itemUserEntity.getCompany());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_name, itemUserEntity.getName());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_job_salary, itemUserEntity.getJob_salary());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_job_mobile, itemUserEntity.getJob_mobile());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_job_email, itemUserEntity.getJob_email());
    contentValues.put(ItemUserSchema.KEY_cate_name, itemUserEntity.getCate_name());

    return db.insertWithOnConflict(ItemUserSchema.TABLE_ITEM_USER,
            null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}}
```

Comment: Why don't you explain to me what this is doing, and why it solves the issue.

Comment: Because your statement SQL incorrect. My answer is eg.

Answer (score 0):

You should to try by applying your SQLiteDatabase Context `onCreate`,
You Should replace.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

with

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mCOntext.getWritableDatabase();
```

One More thing is, it's good habit to write database query in `try{} catch{}` that will be easy to debug.